# Tomcat9 log that I have no idea what to do with

Tags: tomcat9

I saw the following in tomcat logs

> 09-Sep-2019 21:04:04.268 SEVERE [https-jsse-nio2-8443-exec-13]
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process Error
>   reading request, ignored java.lang.NullPointerException

I saw that the fix for the above is to use NIO2 but I already use it.

> 08-Sep-2019 22:32:14.979 INFO [https-jsse-nio2-8443-exec-16]
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service Error parsing HTTP
>   request header  Note: further occurrences of HTTP request parsing
>   errors will be logged at DEBUG level.
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid character found in method
>   name. HTTP method names must be tokens

I read that it's something related to http/https. I'm calling tomcat with https, port 8443 and both clients (mobile app and windows application) are calling it with https... what am I missing?

> 07-Sep-2019 20:50:49.005 INFO [https-jsse-nio2-8443-exec-18]
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.http.Parameters.processParameters Invalid chunk
>   starting at byte [48] and ending at byte [49] with a value of [=]
>   ignored

That I don't even know what it means and why.

Let me know if more info is needed, thanks a lot.

log from undeploy/deploy war if relevant

> 05-Sep-2019 16:37:59.517 INFO [https-jsse-nio2-8443-exec-8]
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.undeploy Undeploying context
>   [/app] 05-Sep-2019 16:38:14.028 INFO [https-jsse-nio2-8443-exec-1]
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deploying web
>   application archive [/opt/tomcat/apache-tomcat-9.0.24/webapps/app.war]
>   05-Sep-2019 16:38:17.971 INFO [https-jsse-nio2-8443-exec-1]
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was
>   scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this
>   logger fo$05-Sep-2019 16:38:18.011 INFO [https-jsse-nio2-8443-exec-1]
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deployment of web
>   application archive [/opt/tomcat/apache-tomcat-9.0.24/webapps/app.war]
>   has$SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
>   SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation SLF4J:
>   See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further
>   details. 05-Sep-2019 16:38:37.418 WARNING [grpc-default-executor-0]
>   io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.internal.MacAddressUtil.defaultMachineId
>   Failed to find a usable hardware address from the network interfaces;
>   u$

Comment: What Java version are you running?

Comment: openjdk11 (vps)

Comment: Did you try to speak HTTPS to a port that is configured for HTTP?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of, the connector is defined as <Connector port="8443"... and both clients are calling with https://www.example.com:8443\mywar.... if it's something outside my scope, how can I know that?

Comment: The third "error" is logged if something connects with an invalid `parameter=value` pair, so either wrong URL in some app or a wrong connection. Do you get any erorrs about your JKS or something on restarting your Tomcat service?

Comment: I do POST with body of parameter=value but it doesn't say the failed request so I don't know if it's one of my tests or real life request that I should handle. Is there a way to know the request? Also, I added a log from undeploy/deploy the war. I didn't see any JKS error but maybe I didn't look in the right place. I do get the first "error" very often.

Comment: I meant from restarting the Tomcat service, not the servlet itself, if possible

Comment: oh, silly question: where can I see the logs of restarting tomcat? btw, the issues from restarting the servlet are something I should do something with?

Comment: By default it's in your catalina log files

Comment: I will need to restart tomcat for that and I prefer to do that after fixing/knowing about the other 2 issues (specially the first one that occurs often). it's a live running server.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/98482/discussion-between-lenniey-and-amos).

Comment: @Lenniey , the chat is still available?